# how to get the index in Handlebars #each Loop

Tags: meteor

I want to get the index of Array  in #each loop,I found a description on the website http://handlebarsjs.com/ :

"When looping through items in each, you can optionally reference the current loop index via {{@index}}"

but I got the errors  when I use the tag {{@index}}

errors:
[image]

The following is my code:

> ```
> <body>
>   {{> hello}}
> </body>
> <template name="hello">
>  {{#each arr}}
>   {{@index}}:{{this}}
>  {{/each}}
> </template>
> ```

```
  Template.hello.arr = function () {
    return ["A","B","C"];
  };
```

Have I forgotten anything? Thank you！

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation of Handlebars for Meteor does not support `@index`. Follow on [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/489).